# Why is there a $ before the name of a variable in coding

Tags: powershell

What does the $ symbol mean? I saw it in this script:

```
function sendColor($colorName)
{
    $portInfo = ( Get-WmiObject Win32_SerialPort | Where { $_.PNPDeviceID -like '*VID_239A*' } | select -last 1 )
    $port = new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort $portInfo.DeviceID,9600,None,8,one
    $port.open()
    $text = $colorName + "`r"
    $port.Write($text)
    start-sleep -m 50
    $port.ReadExisting()
    $port.Close()
}
if ($args.Length -eq 0)
{
    echo "Usage: ColorChange <color>"
}
else
{
    sendColor($args[0])
}
```

As far as I know this is a PowerShell script, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thats the syntax you use in Powershell. A variable always starts with `$` The answer is in your title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the documentation in:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-7

*"A variable is a unit of memory in which values are stored. In PowerShell, variables are represented by text strings that begin with a dollar sign ($), such as $a, $process, or $my_var."*